# How do I run a method when an action is finished

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I was wondering how to call a method after a `CCAction` is finished (I would also like to call it every 2.5 seconds after it is first called). I have a sprite that goes to a random position, and I want it to run this method (a shooting bullet one) after it is done moving to its random position. So far the method is called when it is still moving. Can anyone help?

Here is the enemy create method:

```
(void)enemy1{
    gjk= arc4random()%6;
    enemy1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"enemy1.png"];

    int d = arc4random()%480+480;
    int o = arc4random()%320+320;
    x = arc4random()%480;
    if( x <= 480 && x>= 460){
        x=x-100;
    }
    if(x <= 100){
        x = x+50;
    }

    y = arc4random()%320;
    if(y <=320 && y >= 290){
        y = y-100;
    }
    if(y < 100){
        y = y + 100;
    }
    enemy1.position = ccp(o,d);
    [enemy1 runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3 position: ccp(x,y)]];
    CCRotateBy *rotation = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:20 angle:1080];
    CCRepeatForever * repeatforever = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:rotation];
    [enemy1 runAction:repeatforever];
    [self addChild:enemy1];
    [enemy addObject :enemy1];
}
```

And the method for shooting a projectile:

```
(void)projectileShooting:(ccTime)dt {
    projcount++;
    if(enemy1.position.y < 320){
    v = ccp(player.position.x,player.position.y); 
    for(CCSprite *enemies in enemy){ 
        CCSprite * projectilebullet = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Projectile.png"];
        [proj addObject:projectilebullet];
        [self addChild:projectilebullet];
        CGPoint MyVector = ccpSub(enemies.position,player.position );
        MyVector = ccpNormalize(MyVector);
        MyVector = ccpMult(MyVector, enemies.contentSize.width/2);
        MyVector = ccpMult(MyVector,-1);
        projectilebullet.position = ccpAdd(enemies.position, MyVector);
    }
}
```

The shooting method is called in the init method by the code, so it is called every 2.5 seconds.

```
 [self schedule:@selector(projectileShooting:) interval:2.5];
```

I know I tried to make the shooting happen by making it so that is shoots when the *y* position is < 320, but it is still moving when it passes the position of 320.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding on to Tayyab's answer, you can simply start the actual scheduling of your projectile firing within the *startShooting* method (or whatever you want to call it) which is fired at the end of your move action:

```
[CCSequence actions:
    [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3 position: ccp(x,y)],
    [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startShooting)],
    nil]];
```

where *startShooting* is defined as follows:

```
- (void) startShooting
{
    // start scheduling your projectile to fire every 2.5 seconds
    [self schedule:@selector(projectileShooting:) interval:2.5];
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted! It would have probably taken me a few more days for me to realize how to do what you did to solve my problem haha.

Answer (score 4):

You can make a sequence of actions and at the end of sequence you can give a callback function which will be executed at the end. Something like this

```
[CCSequence actions:
        [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3 position: ccp(x,y)],
        [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(methodToRunAfterAction)],
        nil]];
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It is almost what I wanted. The thing missing is the interval to call it. How would you set an interval?

Comment: If you want an interval use [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:<interval-here>] just put it in the sequence when you want it to happen, probably at the beginning or the end I would imagine?

Comment: what I meant was an interval to keep calling the shooting method every 2.5 or so seconds

Comment: Simply put your scheduling code: "[self schedule:@selector(projectileShooting:) interval:2.5];" in "methodToRunAfterAction".

Comment: I do that with [CCSequence actions:

     [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3 position: ccp(x,y)], [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget: self schedule:@selector(projectileShooting:) interval:2.5], nil];
and it gives me a warning "class method '+actionWithTarget:scheduel:interval:' not found(return type defaults to "id")

Comment: Do the actual scheduling within the "methodToRunAfterAction". See my answer.